# remove node from a single linked list c programming

Tags: c, computer-science, singly-linked-list

There's nothing wrong when i built the program in both VS & codeblock. While, when i ran it, it either broke after i typed in the index number or just show letters infinitely...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


// list_node structure

typedef struct list_node{
    int item;
    struct list_node *next;
}ListNode;
//call functions that will be used 

void printNode(ListNode *head);
int removeNode(ListNode **ptrhead, int index);
ListNode *findNode(ListNode *head, int index);

int main(){
    int index,value;
    ListNode *head=NULL;
    ListNode *temp;
    //build the list  

    printf("Enter a value:");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    do{
              temp->item=value;
        if(head==NULL){
            head=(struct list_node *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp=head;
        }
        else{
            temp->next=(struct list_node *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        printf("Enter a value:");
        scanf("%d",&value);

    }while(value!=-1);

    printf("Enter the index: ");
    scanf("%d",&index);
    // remove the node at the position indexed

    // when I used debugger, I saw it didn't execute this step. Maybe there's something wrong with it....

    removeNode(&head,index);

    printNode(head);

    return 0;
}


void printNode(ListNode *head){
    if (head==NULL)
        exit(0);
    while(head!=NULL){
        printf("%d",head->item);
        head=head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

ListNode *findNode(ListNode *head,int index){
    if(head==NULL||index<0)
        return NULL;
    while(index>0){
        head=head->next;
        index--;
    }
    return head;
}


int removeNode(ListNode **ptrhead,int index){
    ListNode *pre,*cur,*temphead;

    temphead=*ptrhead;

    if(findNode(temphead,index)!=NULL){
        pre=findNode(temphead,index);
        cur=pre->next;
        temphead->next=cur;
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prev=NULL;
cur=head;
/* traverse the list until you find your target */
while (cur != NULL && cur->id != search_id) {
  prev=cur;
  cur=cur->next;
}
/* if a result is found */
if (cur != NULL) {
  /* check for the head of the list */
  if (prev == NULL)
    head=cur->next;
  else
    prev->next=cur->next;  
  /* release the old memory structure */
  free(cur);
}
```

Whats up dude....I hope u will get it...  :)

Answer (score 0):

`temp->item=value;` - you're dereferencing `temp` when it's uninitialized. Undefined behavior, crash and burn.

Comment: should i initialize [temp] or [temp->next]? I thought I already initialized [temp] with [ListNode *temp=NULL;].

Answer (score 0):

In your loop,

```
    temp->item=value;
```

No space has been allocated to temp. Hence, this will crash !!

```
    if(head==NULL){
        head=(struct list_node *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        temp=head;
```

Typically, you woud allocate a `temp` node and assign it to `head` as `head =  temp`. Another point which is missing is when a new node is created, the `next` should be initialized to `NULL` as `temp->next = NULL`

In `removeNode`,

```
    if(findNode(temphead,index)!=NULL){
        pre=findNode(temphead,index);
```

`pre` will be pointing to the node to be removed, but `temphead` will still be pointing to `head` of the list. `findNode` will not modify the `temphead`. So `tmphead->next = cur` will modify the `head` always

Comment: @user2201968 glad to be of help. Hope my answer was sufficient.

Comment: int removeNode(ListNode **ptrhead,int index){
 ListNode *pre,*cur;
 if (index==-1)
  return 1;
 else if(findNode((*ptrhead),(index))!=NULL){
  pre=findNode((*ptrhead),(index-1));
  cur=pre->next;
  pre->next=cur->next;
  return 0;
 }
 else
  return 1;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
int removeNode(ListNode **ptrhead,int index){
ListNode *pre,*cur;
if (index==-1)
    return 1;
else if(findNode((*ptrhead),(index))!=NULL){
    pre=findNode((*ptrhead),(index-1));
    cur=pre->next;
    pre->next=cur->next;
    return 0;
}
else
    return 1;
}
```

I modified the last part and added`temp->next=NULL`in the main function. this program can ran well now!